# android custom obligatory attributes

Tags: android, attributes

I use custom attributes for custom layout styling in Android. I would like to make such an attribute obligatory, i.e.:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyLayout">
    <attr name="my_attr" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>

<com.example.MyLayout
    android:other_attributes="blabla" >
<com.example.MyLayout/>
```

Is it possible that such an attempt to define a MyLayout without my_attr will fail at a compile time?